# Как вывести 0 если нет данных в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT t1.calldate, 
    t2.answered, 
    t3.no_answer 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(calldate)) AS calldate 
     FROM calls c
    ) AS t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(calldate)) AS calldate, 
                    COUNT(ID) AS answered 
                FROM calls 
                WHERE disposition = 1 
                    AND did = '555' 
                    AND MONTH(calldate) = 08  
                    AND YEAR(calldate) = 2017 
                GROUP BY 1
               ) t2 ON t1.calldate = t2.calldate
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(calldate)) AS calldate, 
                    COUNT(ID) AS no_answer 
                FROM calls 
                WHERE disposition <> 1 
                    AND did = '555' 
                    AND MONTH(calldate) = 08 
                    AND YEAR(calldate) = 2017  
                GROUP BY 1
               ) AS t3 ON t1.calldate = t3.calldate;
```

Выводит t1.calldate и t2.answered (если брать отдельно), а вот t3.no_answer ничего. В базе данных нет значений где disposition <> 1. А как сделать чтобы вместо "ничего" выводились нули? Всем заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Может условием,`if (empty($res)) echo 0;`, где `$res = результат выборки`.

Comment: Благодарю, но, необходимо внести изменения в запросе, а не в php.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319264/return-a-default-value-if-no-rows-found

Comment: Есть функция `ifnull()`

Comment: Наверное, я не правильно задал вопрос. Исправил.

Comment: SELECT t1.calldate, COALESCE(t2.answered, 0), COALESCE(t3.no_answer, 0)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(calldate) AS calldate,
        SUM(    disposition = 1 
            AND did = '555' 
            AND MONTH(calldate) = 08  
            AND YEAR(calldate) = 2017) AS answered,
        SUM(    disposition <> 1 
            AND did = '555' 
            AND MONTH(calldate) = 08 
            AND YEAR(calldate) = 2017) AS no_answer
FROM calls
GROUP BY DATE(calldate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте IFNULL:

```
IFNULL(t3.no_answer, "null")
```

или
 `IFNULL(t3.no_answer, 0)`

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/

Comment: По прежнему ничего не выводит, может быть вы укажите в каком месте нужно делать проверку?

Comment: IFNULL(t3.no_answer, 0)

Comment: это не подойдет, надо SELECT t1.calldate, SUM(t2.answered), SUM(t3.no_answer)

Comment: Это понятно) Уже попробовал изменить и в подзапросе и на выводе, не работает..

Comment: @YuriGo пригляделся в отредактированный код. Поставьте LEFT JOIN вместо второго JOIN.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум, третий запрос не нужен, можно сделать через `sum` подсчёт количества. Как я понял, для каждой даты вам нужно количество звонков. `INNER JOIN` соединяет только там, где есть звонки с указанными условиями. Используйте `LEFT JOIN` с `ifnull` в итоговом `select`:

```
SELECT t1.calldate, 
    ifnull(t2.answered, 0) as answered, 
    ifnull(t2.no_answer, 0) as no_answer
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(calldate)) AS calldate 
     FROM calls c
    ) AS t1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(calldate)) AS calldate, 
                    SUM(if(disposition = 1, 1, 0)) AS answered,
                    SUM(if(disposition <> 1, 1, 0)) as no_answer
                FROM calls 
                WHERE did = '555' 
                    AND MONTH(calldate) = 08  
                    AND YEAR(calldate) = 2017 
                GROUP BY 1
               ) t2 ON t1.calldate = t2.calldate
```

Comment: Выводит 0 и в answered и в no_answer - так не должно быть, в answered есть значения это 100%

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался) Проблема была в том, что я использовал полное соединение (INNER JOIN) вместо LEFT JOIN, в том месте где нет данных)

```
 SELECT t1.calldate, t2.answered, IFNULL(t3.no_answer,0) AS no_answer FROM(SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(calldate)) AS calldate FROM calls c) AS t1
 INNER JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(calldate)) AS calldate, COUNT(ID) AS answered FROM calls WHERE disposition = 1 AND did = '555' AND MONTH(calldate) = 08  AND YEAR(calldate) = 2017 GROUP BY 1) t2 ON t1.calldate = t2.calldate
 LEFT JOIN(SELECT DISTINCT(DATE(calldate)) AS calldate, COUNT(ID) AS no_answer FROM calls WHERE disposition <> 1 AND did = '555' AND MONTH(calldate) = 08 AND YEAR(calldate) = 2017  GROUP BY 1) AS t3 ON t1.calldate = t3.calldate;
```

Comment: Мы, несомненно, рады, что вы разобрались сами.) А решение с LEFT JOIN вам советовал @tcpack4 (в комментариях выше) за 15 минут до вашего ответа.